# html style specific words without tags

Tags: html, styles

Is any way to auto-style words?
I wanna create a code that every time i write a specific word like "fire" and "ice" take red and blue color respectively without being in between tags like spawn, p, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean "without tags", before your code runs, or also after?

Comment: I mean i don't want <spawn | p | etc>fire</spawn | p | etc> on the body and style="color: red;" ..... I wanna write just the word "fire" and take color red every time i write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with jquery:

Here's an Exemple.

```js
var StringFire = 'Fire',
    newStringFire = '<span>Fire</span>',
    newTextFire = $('p').text().replace(RegExp(StringFire,"gi"),newStringFire);

$('p').html(newTextFire);
```

```css
span{
    color: red;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Fire and Ice. Launch Audio in a New Window. By Robert Frost. Some say the world will end in fire,. Some say in ice. From what I've tasted of desire. I hold with those who favor fire. But if it had to perish twice,. I think I know enough of hate. To say that for destruction ice. Is also great. And would suffice. n/a. More About this ...</p>
```

For Multiple Words :

```js
var text = $('p').html().replace(/Ice/gi, "<span class='ice'>Ice</span>");
$('p').html(text);

var text = $('p').html().replace(/Fire/gi, "<span class='fire'>Fire</span>");
$('p').html(text);
```

```css
.ice {
  color: blue;
  font: sans-serif;
}

.fire {
  color: red;
  font: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Fire and Ice. Launch Audio in a New Window. By Robert Frost. Some say the world will end in fire,. Some say in ice. From what I've tasted of desire. I hold with those who favor fire. But if it had to perish twice,. I think I know enough of hate. To say that for destruction ice. Is also great. And would suffice. n/a. More About this ...</p>
```

Comment: This works but how can i use more than 1 word? And fix the search problem by finding the ice to words like "twice"?

Comment: This works perfect. Also i changed the "replace(/ice/gi, " with "replace(/\bice\b/gi, " and now searching only the excact word ice and not finding the tw**ice** and suff**ice**

Comment: /fire/g to search words excatly :
str.replace(/fire/g, "red");

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use a script?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#searchfor').keyup(function(){
     page = $('#all_text').text();
     searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
     $("p:contains('"+searchedText+"')").css("color", "red");
});
```

});

Comment: But, what is this?